# what is the best approach to parse xml data to make it as generic as possible in Qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt, parsing

I'm trying to find a good and effective way to parse an XML data structure that different API calls are returning.  The problem is that each time I need different data and each time I'm getting a different XML structure.  Which is better: to use the SAX approach or The DOM approach? Does QT 4.6 recommend or work better with one of the approaches?

Thanks

Comment: You really should add some spaces and new-lines... (I wish I could do it myself). And this is more XML-related than Qt-related.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286842/how-do-i-run-xpath-queries-in-qt) and its answers. The magic word is [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) queries and QT 4.6 has [support](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qxmlquery.html#running-xpath-expressions) for it.