# Reading and using PHP generated XML in Qt

Tags: xml, qt

Hello
I'm building an Qt application which, amongst other things displays products of a store. The products are stored in a MySQL database, which is queried by php functions. The PHP function returns an XML of the contents of table.
So, I've been looking for a while, but I can't find an elegant soulution for my problem.
What I need is:
1. get the XML from the function (domain.com/blah.php)
2. get data from the XML
So, is it possible for me to use XML data as if i'm working with objects. Example of the data is:

```
<categories> 
<category> 
    <ID>1</ID> 
    <Category_name>Hrana i pica</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>0</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>2</ID> 
    <Category_name>Kucne potrepstine</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>0</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>3</ID> 
    <Category_name>Ljepota i njega</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>0</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>4</ID> 
    <Category_name>Djecji svijet</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>0</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>5</ID> 
    <Category_name>Cvijece</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>0</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>6</ID> 
    <Category_name>Akcijska prodaja</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>0</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>7</ID> 
    <Category_name>Alkoholna pica</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>8</ID> 
    <Category_name>Bezalkoholna pica</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>9</ID> 
    <Category_name>Delikatesa specijal</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>10</ID> 
    <Category_name>Delikatese / mesne preradevine</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>11</ID> 
    <Category_name>Dijabetski i zdrava hrana</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>12</ID> 
    <Category_name>Dorucak</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>13</ID> 
    <Category_name>Mlijecni, jaja i sir</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>14</ID> 
    <Category_name>Namirnice za pripremu jela</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>15</ID> 
    <Category_name>Pekarski proizvodi</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>16</ID> 
    <Category_name>Slatkisi i grickalice</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>17</ID> 
    <Category_name>Smrznuto</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>18</ID> 
    <Category_name>Svjeza riba</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>19</ID> 
    <Category_name>Svjeze meso</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>20</ID> 
    <Category_name>Svjeze voce i povrce</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>21</ID> 
    <Category_name>Ukiseljena i konzerv. hrana</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>1</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>22</ID> 
    <Category_name>Elektro pribor i medija</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>23</ID> 
    <Category_name>Higijenski i papirnati proizvodi</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>24</ID> 
    <Category_name>Kiosk</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>25</ID> 
    <Category_name>Knjige za odrasle</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>26</ID> 
    <Category_name>Kucanske potrepstine</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>27</ID> 
    <Category_name>Kucni ljubimci</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>28</ID> 
    <Category_name>Party program</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>29</ID> 
    <Category_name>Posudje i oprema za dom</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>30</ID> 
    <Category_name>Sezonski asortiman</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>31</ID> 
    <Category_name>Sportska odjeca i oprema</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>32</ID> 
    <Category_name>Sredstva za pranje i ciscenje</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>33</ID> 
    <Category_name>Skolski i uredski asortiman</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>34</ID> 
    <Category_name>Tekstil i obuca</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>35</ID> 
    <Category_name>Ukrasi i prigodni program</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>36</ID> 
    <Category_name>Uradi sam</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>37</ID> 
    <Category_name>Vrt i kamp</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>2</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>38</ID> 
    <Category_name>Dekorativna kozmetika i parfemi</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>3</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>39</ID> 
    <Category_name>Muska kozmetika</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>3</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>40</ID> 
    <Category_name>Njega kose</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>3</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>41</ID> 
    <Category_name>Njega lica za zene</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>3</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>42</ID> 
    <Category_name>Njega tijela</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>3</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>43</ID> 
    <Category_name>Njega zubi</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>3</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>44</ID> 
    <Category_name>Djecja galanterija</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>4</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>45</ID> 
    <Category_name>Djecja hrana</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>4</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>46</ID> 
    <Category_name>Djecja kozmetika i higijena</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>4</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>47</ID> 
    <Category_name>Djecji svijet - ostalo</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>4</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>48</ID> 
    <Category_name>Igracke</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>4</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>49</ID> 
    <Category_name>Knjige za djecu</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>4</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>50</ID> 
    <Category_name>Tekstil odjevni za bebe</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>4</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>51</ID> 
    <Category_name>Trudnice i dojilje</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>4</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>52</ID> 
    <Category_name>Cvijece i bilje</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>5</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>53</ID> 
    <Category_name>Cvjecarski pribor</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>5</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>54</ID> 
    <Category_name>Zemlja</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>5</Parent_ID> 
</category> 
<category> 
    <ID>55</ID> 
    <Category_name>Proizvodi na akciji</Category_name> 
    <Parent_ID>6</Parent_ID> 
</category>
```

So, what I would like to be able to do, is for example query all of the categories with the same Parent_ID.

Any ideas?
(Sorry if it's a dumb question, but I just can't figure this out)

Answer (score 1):

How to download a file over HTTP: http://www.qtforum.org/article/29846/qhttp-problem-with-the-timeout.html

The basic gist here is to use [QUrl](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qurl.html) and [QHttp](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdoc.trolltech.com%2Fqhttp.html&ei=hGCuTOb_J4_IvQPSk-nzBg&usg=AFQjCNHmWITDSDbffqz02h3JJhUtRcyPEw&sig2=eRWRzhNqxRjhz5y9lHP64w) classes. Start the HTTP request and connect to the QHttp object's `done` signal to act on the file when the download is complete.

How to read an XML file: http://www.qtforum.org/article/27624/how-to-read-a-xml-file.html

Answer (score 1):

You can match nodes in XML using xpath expressions:

```
number(/category/Parent_ID)=1 # for Parent_ID of 1.
```

To evaluate an XPath expression in Qt, see [How do I run XPath queries in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286842/how-do-i-run-xpath-queries-in-qt)