# Parsing html with qt?

Tags: c++, html, xml, qt, xpath

How can I extract from a html page some content in the easiest way, such as for example all the strong tags whose parents are p and are of class A ? The xpath equivalent would be .//p[@class='A']/strong.

Comment: You can just use xpath as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286842/how-do-i-run-xpath-queries-in-qt

Edit: I was wrong, that only works for XML documents.

Comment: Yes, and my page is not xhtml

Comment: "The easiest way" is very, very debatable; is it *easy enough* for you to use QtWebkit to parse the page, and then use `QWebFrame::findAllElements` + a CSS2 selector to get what you want? (Or, you could inject jQuery and then use it to navigate the dom)

Answer (score 1):

> "The easiest way" is very, very debatable; is it easy enough for you to use QtWebkit to parse the page, and then use QWebFrame::findAllElements + a CSS2 selector to get what you want? (Or, you could inject jQuery and then use it to navigate the dom)