# Trying to get a string out of an XML document with QXmlQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, qt5.5, qxmlquery

Starting with a simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<playlist>
    <name>1 - first playlist</name>

    <song>Daft Punk\Discovery\Daft Punk-Discovery-01-One More Time.mp3</song>
</playlist>
```

I found:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qxmlquery.html
- [How do I run XPath queries in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286842/how-do-i-run-xpath-queries-in-qt)

I'm trying to extract the playlist name, so I tried:

```
QFile source(filePath);
source.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
query.setFocus(&source);
query.setQuery("string(//name)", QUrl(filePath));

QString result = "";
query.evaluateTo(&result);

qDebug() << result;

source.close();
```

filePath is a QString passed in this method.

No matter what I do, I keep getting "Parse error: start tag expected" from the file being loaded, and no result. When I check what is in the file it looks correct.

Comment: Why have you used `QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);` instead of simply the default? Without knowing the API, I suspect as you ask for XSLT 2.0 later on when you pass in an XPath/XQuery expression the processor tries to parse that expression as an XSLT/XML document which it not is.

Comment: Because the documentation didn't have a specific example for xpath. That is one thing I didn't try...

Comment: @MartinHonnen - want to make that an answer, because that is what fixed it - thanks.

Comment: I have put the suggestion in an answer so you can accept it and mark your issue as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);` you are requesting XSLT and not XPath or XQuery, I suspect that you then get the described error as the library tries to parse the provided XPath or XQuery expression as an XML document (as XSLT is XML but XPath or XQuery is not XML). So simply use the default constructor or explicitly set the language as `QXmlQuery::XQuery10`.